# Save a copy of sent email to a folder

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, basic

One of our users has a script set up which pops up with a folder view when "Send" is clicked. This allows the sent email to be put in to a folder they choose.

The issue is, that they want the email to still go into "Sent Items" as well as their chosen folder.

Any help would be grand.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                                 Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objNS = Application.Session
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
        If Not objFolder Is Nothing And _
          IsInDefaultStore(objFolder) And _
          objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder
        Else
            Set objFolder = _
              objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
            Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder
        End If
    End If
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
Public Function IsInDefaultStore(objOL As Object) As Boolean
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim blnBadObject As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objApp = objOL.Application
    If Err = 0 Then
        Set objNS = objApp.Session
        Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Select Case objOL.Class
            Case olFolder
                If objOL.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
                    IsInDefaultStore = True
                Else
                    IsInDefaultStore = False
                End If
            Case olAppointment, olContact, olDistributionList, _
                 olJournal, olMail, olNote, olPost, olTask
                If objOL.Parent.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
                    IsInDefaultStore = True
                Else
                    IsInDefaultStore = False
                End If
            Case Else
                blnBadObject = True
        End Select
    Else
        blnBadObject = True
    End If
    If blnBadObject Then
        MsgBox "This function isn't designed to work " & _
                "with " & TypeName(objOL) & _
                " objects and will return False.", _
                , "IsInDefaultStore"
        IsInDefaultStore = False
    End If
    Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
End Function
```

EDIT:

I added this:

```
Set msg = Item.Copy
msg.Move objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
```

Which worked. but it doesn't save any date information at all. it saves a copy, but the date in "sent items" comes up as "None". and the email is displayed as unread.

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to do this, is simply set up a rule that copies every sent email to the "Sent Items" folder.

The only issue is that the emails appear as unread.